# Error: Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE

Tags: system-tray

I am attempting to run Rescuetime on ubuntu 16.04 and getting the following error:

> "sni-qt/17399" WARN  17:25:14.323 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE 
>   No systemtrayicon available
>
> (rescuetime:17399): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to connect to ibus: Could not connect: Connection refused
>   No systemtrayicon available

Any advice on how I can solve this?